# Trying to join two tables by IDs in two column (Error No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, ARRAY<INT64>.)

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having troubles joining tables by these columns. It appears that *c.vid* column is an ARRAY while *d.associations.associatedvids* is an INT64 type. What is the best way to convert an array to a INT64? At first glance, they both look identical. I'm coming from Postgres and I cannot wrap my head around it. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the error:

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, ARRAY<INT64>. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [2:26]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to use unnest() on associations.associatedvids column.

Here is the final query:

```
SELECT associated_vid,d.dealid FROM hs.deals AS d, unnest(associations.associatedvids) as associated_vid
JOIN hs.contacts as c on c.vid = associated_vid
```

Comment: I would guess whomever created your `deals` table knows/assumes that each deal could have multiple associations/associatedvids.  Using nested arrays like this is good practice in BQ for query performance and storage costs.

Comment: Yeah, we were using Postgres before which had a separate table for associations. This is fine by Stich(ETL)